# How to write to a file saved in local folder in Android

Tags: android

I am having a file in the folder res/raw/a.xml.
I want to write some data to this file?
How it can be done in Android?
How can we access a file stored in local directory in order to write data to that file. 
can anyone help me in sorting out this issue ?
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Please, tell why you need to write to this file? What's the purpose?

Comment: Vladimir's comment might seem a bit agressive, but it's a legit question. If you want to store data relating to the app, it's generally a good idea to consider the `SQLiteDatabase` or `Preference` classes.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi, I am having a file in the folder res/raw/a.xml. I want to write some data to this file? How it can be done in Android?

You cannot modify a resource at runtime, sorry.

> How can we access a file stored in local directory in order to write data to that file.

Use `getFilesDir()` to get a `File` object pointing to your app's local directory. Then, use standard Java I/O.